# How can I create arc shape ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an application with some buttons. I want to create a arc shape button like the following image[image]

How can I do it? I use the following code to achieve this.

```
button.layer.cornerRadius =  button.bounds.size.height
```

and

```
button.layer.cornerRadius =  0.5*button.bounds.size.height
```

I also tried this with the using of width

```
button.layer.cornerRadius =  button.bounds.size.width
```

and

```
button.layer.cornerRadius =  0.5*button.bounds.size.width
```

How can I do it? Please someone help me to solve this.

Comment: What's the button, in the image?

Comment: There is an arc shape (semi circle) with gray color.

Comment: So it's supposed to have a flat top and bottom?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but for custom drawing, you can use Paint Code (http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) to draw and then copy the code. You can use trial version for something like this, so don't have to pay.

Comment: It's a fairly complex shape, so you should probably look into drawing it using [`UIBezierPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/). Apple provides a [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html).

Comment: @ishaq I tried now with paintcode. It is confusing. Don't know how to make my shape. Any help

Comment: @TimVermeulen Could you help me to create this?

Comment: @Amsheer here's a good tutorial for paint code: http://www.raywenderlich.com/92972/paintcode-tutorial-for-developers-getting-started , Trust me the time you would spend in learning it won't be wasted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create arc shape you need to use **UIBezierPath**
please read apple's  [**UIBezierPath_class**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/) Document.

They have mention method for create arc shape.

[Creates and returns a new UIBezierPath object initialized with an arc of a circle.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)

[image]

For constructing the path

[Appends an arc to the receiver’s path.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)

[image]

You can also Refer [**Core Graphics Tutorial Part 1**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1) With Example and search with **arc** keyword on browser you will redirect to arc shape on the page.

Comment: Possibly you should setup your button class to have CAShapeLayer as its layerClass, and when you init it, set it up with this Bezier path.

Answer (score 2):

Another image posted by @Jack in above comments and asked help, here is the image:

[image]

I couldn't answer him as comment, so pasting my playground here instead.

```
let shapeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 360, height: 60))
let shapeSize = shapeView.frame.size
shapeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let path = CGMutablePath()
path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)

let curveWidthOneFourth = shapeSize.width / 4
let curveHeight = shapeSize.height * 0.2
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: curveWidthOneFourth * 2, y: curveHeight), control1: .zero, control2: CGPoint(x: curveWidthOneFourth, y: curveHeight))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: shapeSize.width, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: curveWidthOneFourth * 3, y: curveHeight), control2: CGPoint(x: shapeSize.width, y: 0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shapeSize.width, y: shapeSize.height))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: shapeSize.height))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint.zero)
```

And add our path to a view's layer:

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.path = path
layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

Comment: ✌thats what i looking FOR 

Answer (score 1):

Encountered a similar task today, I used `CGMutableShape` instead of `UIBezierPath` because I was required to animation the shape.

Anyways, to understand the shape I divided the shape into 6 parts (lines & curves):

[image]

---

**Base UIView to draw our shape in**

```
let shapeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 16, width: 100, height: 44))
shapeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
self.view.addSubview(shapeView)
```

**Actual shape and its path**

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0)) // Move path to beginning of part-1

// Draw above divided parts
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 0)) // Part-1
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 95, y: 22), control1: CGPoint(x: 93, y: 6.6), control2: CGPoint(x: 95, y: 14)) // Part-2
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 44), control1: CGPoint(x: 95, y: 30), control2: CGPoint(x: 93, y: 37)) // Part-3
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 44))  // Part-4
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 22), control1: CGPoint(x: 7, y: 37), control2: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 30)) // Part-5
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 14), control2: CGPoint(x: 6, y: 6.6)) // Part-6

let arcLayer = CAShapeLayer()
arcLayer.path = path
arcLayer.fillColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

shapeView.layer.insertSublayer(arcLayer, at: 0)
```

Comment: Hey Jack, couldn't paste my playground here, posting another answer